# Unable to resolve service in C# net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

After launch my endpoint at `localhost:5002/Data` console throw me this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'db.Service.IDataService' while attempting to activate 'db.Controllers.DataController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
```

Can someone tell me what i'am doing wrong?

my code:

DatService.cs

```
    public class DataService : IDataService
    {


        public DataService(){}
        

        public List<DataDTO> ParseCsvToJson()
        {
            List<DataDTO> dataDTOs = new List<DataDTO>();
            List<Data> list = data.Where(a => a.age.Equals("48")).ToList();
            foreach(var a in list)
            {
                DataDTO dataDTO = new DataDTO();
                dataDTO.name = a.name; //IT IS GOOD SETTER?
                dataDTO.id = a.id;
                dataDTOs.Add(dataDTO);
            }
            return dataDTOs;
        }
    }
```

IDataService.cs

```
    public interface IDataService
    {
        List<DataDTO> ParseCsvToJson();
    }
```

DataController.cs

```
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    
        public DataController(
            IDataService dataService
        ){
            _dataService = dataService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<DataDTO> GetList()
        {
            List<DataDTO> values = _dataService.ParseCsvToJson();
            return values;
        }

    }
```

thanks for any answer

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: How you add `DataService` to services?

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I don't understand the question :/

Comment: Did you register IDataService with the Dependency Injection system? Can you show your startup.cs class?

Comment: @Crowcoder no, i do not register, can you show me how do this?

Comment: Can you first clarify what version of mvc it is? Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: You need to register your service in `ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs. See [Dependecy injection to controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for details.

Comment: thanks guys, you help me, now it work :) thanks, i'm new in net core, earlier i'm coding in java/spring